# Python - How to Create Dictionary from CSV data file using column headings

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to create a function that accepts the name of a .csv data file and a list of strings representing column headings in that file and return a dict object with each key being a column heading and the corresponding value being a numpy array of the values in that column of the data file.

My code right now:

```
def columndata(filename, columns):
d = dict()
for col in columns:
with open(filename) as filein:
    reader = csv.reader(filein)
        for row in reader:
           if col in row:
               d.append(row)
return d
```

The sample CSV looks like:

```
test1,test2
3,2
1,5
6,47
1,4
```

The columns file looks like:

```
cols = ['test1', 'test2']
```

The end result should be a dictionary like this:

```
{'test1':[3,1,6,1], 'test2':[2, 5, 4, 4]}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) which parse the CSV data into a dict:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict


def parse_csv_by_field(filename, fieldnames):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
        next(reader)  # remove header
        for row in reader:
            for field in fieldnames:
                d[field].append(float(row[field]))  # thanks to Paulo!
    return dict(d)

print(parse_csv_by_field('a.csv', fieldnames=['cattle', 'cost']))
```

Comment: Why `extend` instead of `append`?

Comment: Oups, I should have use append without the list you're right!

Answer (score 4):

A simple pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename', dtype='float') #you wanted float datatype
dict = df.to_dict(orient='list')
```

If you want to stick with regular python:

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    l = list(csv.reader(f))
    dict = {i[0]:[float(x) for x in i[1:]] for i in zip(*l)}
```

Or if you're a master of being pythonic like Adam Smith:

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    l = list(csv.reader(f))
    dict = {header: list(map(float, values)) for header, *values in zip(*l)}
```

Comment: In `pandas`, may be `.to_dict(orient='list')` will give desired result

Comment: Also, I think it is good to name `dict` to some other variable name `my_dict`. If you try: `my_dict = {i[0]:list(i[1:]) for i in zip(*l)}`, it will give list instead of tuple for values in `my_dict`

Comment: Good use of the `cols = zip(*rows)` idiom. Might I suggest `my_dict = {header: values for header, *values in zip(*l)}`? (Valid only in py3)

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE I don't get that as a result, but you can convert it into a list while converting to floats

Comment: @Primusa you can preserve the `float` cast by either replacing `header: values` with `header: map(float, values)` or `header: [float(v) for v in values]`

Comment: this solution doesn't work with 16GB files..... looking for a way to do that without pre-loading the entire file.