# How to create a dictionary from a comma-separated values?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a dictionary from a text file that contains comma-separated values.
So far I wrote this much.

```
import csv
pick = open('a.txt','r')
read = csv.reader(pick)
reviews = {}
```

The sample data in the text file looks like this

```
Peter,Gravity,4.5,For a Few Dollars More,1.0,Prometheus,4.0
Jack Holmes,Lawrence of Arabia,3.0,Gravity,3.5,The Godfather,1.5,Prometheus,5.0,The Guns of Navarone,3.0
```

And I want to create a dictionary that should look like this

```
{'Peter': {'Gravity': 4.5,
          'For a Few Dollars More': 1.0,
          'Prometheus': 4.0},

'Jack Holmes': {'Lawrence of Arabia': 3.0,
                'Gravity': 3.5,
                'The Godfather': 1.5,
                'Prometheus': 5.0,
                'The Guns of Navarone': 3.0,}
}
```

I looked on these pages: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file)
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868034/python-how-to-create-dictionary-from-csv-data-file-using-column-headings)
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943126/creating-a-dictionary-from-csv-using-python)
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685363/python-csv-to-dictionary-columnwise) but didn't help to answer my question.
Could you give me some hints or ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: <br> would be there at end of each line?

Comment: @SubbuVidyaSekar, <br> was a typo. No there won't be a <br> at the end of each line.

Comment: at the end of each line, any possibility for enter key press or continuous lines?

Comment: @SubbuVidyaSekar, continuous lines. Since, a file has to be read so, need for the key press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses `zip` to pair the keys and values for the interior dictionaries.

```
d = {}

with open('a.txt') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        it = iter(line)
        key = next(it)
        d[key] = dict(zip(it, it))
```

If you need `float` values, you can do something like

```
d[key] = dict((a, float(b)) for a, b in zip(it, it))
```

Comment: change to **key = next(it)** its a typo

Comment: @Patrick Haugh, your solution worked. This is what I wanted. Thank you!
Btw, please edit  the part key = next(it).

Comment: @007mrviper: validate your result. still some work is there. the whole list is coming as value for the key

Comment: @SubbuVidyaSekar I already did. That's why I accepted his answer.

Comment: {'Peter': {'Gravity': '4.5',
  'For a Few Dollars More': '1.0',
  'Prometheus': '4.0',
  'Jack Holmes': 'Lawrence of Arabia',
  '3.0': 'Gravity',
  '3.5': 'The Godfather',
  '1.5': 'Prometheus',
  '5.0': 'The Guns of Navarone'}} this is the result you might get..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not so great but simple solution:

```
import csv

mydict = {}
with open('file.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    mylist = list(reader)
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        z = iter(mylist[i][1:])
        mydict[mylist[i][0]] = dict(zip(z, z))

print(mydict)
```